# Is it true, If $A$ is turing recognizable and $A \leq_m\bar{A}$ then $A$ is recursive?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

If $A$ is turing recognizable and $A \leq_m\bar{A}$ then $A$ is recursive? 
If it is true how to prove it?

**Update**

It is my attempt, If $A$ is turing recognizable (r.e.) and $\bar{A}$ is r.e. then $A$ is recursive. but by $A \leq_m\bar{A}$ I can't deduce that $\bar{A}$ is r.e.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DavidRicherby From what I know if $A$ is r.e. (turing recognizable) and $B \leq_m A$ then B is r.e.  If $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are r.e. then $A$ is recursive. the problem is I can't deduce that $\bar{A}$ is r.e.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I posted my prove as the answer, would you please take a look at it to see if it is right?

Comment: @Drupalist We don't do homework grading, sorry. You should be able to convince yourself that your proof is correct (that's an advantage of mathematics). If you think there's a gap, that makes for a more specific question than "am I correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I proved it this way**, first we need a few definitions:

> $co-W = \{A | \overline{A} \in W\}$
>
> set $W$ is called *m-closed* if for $A \in W$, and for any $B \leq_mA$ then $B \in W$

We already knew (Davis book page 209)

> If $W$ is m-closed or 1-closed then so is $co-W$

Because the set of all $r.e.$ sets is m-closed so is $co-r.e.$,

$A \in r.e. \rightarrow \overline{A}\in co-r.e.$ *//by definition*

$A \leq_m \overline{A}$ because $\overline{A} \in co-r.e.$ and $co-r.e.$ set is m-closed so $A \in co-r.e.$

$A \in co-r.e.$ it implies $\overline{A} \in r.e.$

$A \in r.e. \land \overline{A}\in r.e. \rightarrow A \in recursive$

and the proof is completed

---

It implies any set $\psi$ that is m-closed or 1-closed, if $A\in\psi$ and $A \leq_m \overline{A}$ or $A\in\psi$ and $A \leq_1 \overline{A}$, then $\overline{A}\in\psi$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $A$ reduces to $\overline{A}$ then $\overline{A}$ reduces to $A$ (using the same reduction).

Comment: Your answer means there is no R.E. set say $A$ such that $\bar{A}$ is not R.E and $A \leq_m\bar{A}$ , is it really right?!

Comment: I meant what I wrote. You draw the conclusions.

Comment: If $A$ is R.E and $\bar{A}$ is not then $\bar{A} \leq_m A$ is a contradiction, because this reduction says $\bar{A}$ must be R.E! If your answer is true then there must be two disjoint cases: whether $\bar{A}$ must be R.E or $A$ is not mapping reducible to $\bar{A}$

Comment: I posted my prove as the answer, would you please take a look at it to see if it is right?

Comment: That's the job of your TA, not mine.